# Could not load file or assembly DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, aspose, aspose.words

I am trying to implement A DLL into an existing project. I am getting this Error:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'Aspose.Words, Version=21.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=716fcc553a201e56' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Aspose.Words, Version=21.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=716fcc553a201e56"}  System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

Every time it try to run the method that creates the Aspose(dll) object it goes straight to catch, with this message. But it's odd though because when i Run the exact same code with the exact same package and path, it works just fine in a new standalone program.

Any tips ?

Comment: Can you share some more information? What is your runtime? Is that DLL compatible with your runtime? Did you make any changes with that DLL properties (such as "Build Action" or "Copy to Output Directory")? 

One more question. Is this DLL integrated to your .net project with IKVM support by any chance?

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems quite straightforward, windows can't find the .dll. So probably the reference points to nowhere. Can you try to debug and see where exactly does it look for it, in what location? Then open file explorer and verify if it actually exists there.

It might look for the .Dll in project or in Global Assembly Cache. Try cleaning the cache and try again.

Comment: I forgot to add it in Gac thank you!